# Internal Server Error when using Meteor.loginWithFacebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, oauth

Using the `service-configuration` and `accounts-facebook` packages, after clicking on the facebook button and logging in from the Facebook authorization window that pops up, we're getting an `Internal server error` when performing a `Meteor.loginWithFacebook`.

This was tested on a very basic example, what is causing this error?

```
Template.login.events({
    'click .btn-facebook': function (ev) {
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(error) {
            if(error) {
                throw new Meteor.Error('Facebook login failed: ', error);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

**/server/lib/config/social.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
    { service: "facebook" },
    { $set: {
        appId: "xxx",
        secret: "xxx"
      }
    },
    { upsert: true }
  );

})
```

**Error (server side)**

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' undefined
```

**Error (client side)**

```
Error: Internal server error [500]
    at _.extend._livedata_result (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:4964:23)
    at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3725:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:2717:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:11)
    at _.extend._launchConnection.self.socket.onmessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:2716:11)
    at REventTarget.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:156:22)
    at SockJS._dispatchMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:1141:10)
    at SockJS._didMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:1199:18)
    at WebSocket.SockJS.websocket.that.ws.onmessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:1346:17)
```

Comment: Do you have any Accounts.onXXXX hooks on your server?

Comment: @Akshat No I dont, is it required?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and solved it like this :

After checking that you have configured your schema as described [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/issues/282) :

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String
    }
    ...
});
```

You should add the second part into an `Accounts.onCreateUser` like this, into `server/accounts.js` for example :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  if (user.services.facebook) {
    user.emails = [{
      address: user.services.facebook.email,
      verified: true
    }];
  }
  return user;
});
```

It will append the facebook email to the newly created account. The error should disapear.